# получение на вход json файла, изменение значений и запись в новый json файл

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

есть json файл

```
{
    "A": [
    {
       "B": 0, 
       "C": 1
    }
    ], 
    "D": [
    {
       "E": 2, 
       "F": 4}
    ]
}
```

я подаю его на вход программе, она должна его прочитать и изменить данные у полей "B" и допустим "C".

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('newtest.json')
data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
data['A'].append({'B':50,'C':50})
path.write_text(json.dumps(data,sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')), encoding='utf-8')
```

в результате работы программы получается так, что данные дублируются и на выходе имеется вот такой файл

```
{
    "A": [
    {
        "B": 0,
        "C": 1
    },
    {
        "B": 50,
        "C": 50
    }
    ],
    "D": [
    {
        "E": 2,
        "F": 4
    }
    ]
}
```

как избежать дублирования и просто презаписать этот файл, или, если можно, создать новый файл .json и записать все новые данные туда, с сохранением структурного вида?

Comment: data['A'] = {'B':50,'C':50}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В 4 строке вы добавляете новый словарь в массив, а надо его "заменить", через присвоение.

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('newtest.json')
data = json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
data['A'] = {'B':50,'C':50} # не добавление в массив, а присвоение
path.write_text(json.dumps(data,sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')), encoding='utf-8')
```